# Java heap space while trying to fetch topic list in Java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am getting heap space issue while my code is trying to fetch topics from Kafka.
Kafka client I am using is org apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0

I generated the heap dump for the issue as well.
Please find the dump analysis

One instance of java.lang.ThreadGroup loaded by  occupies 20,28,69,120 (93.21%) bytes. The instance is referenced by org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread @ 0xef82aac8 kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-664, loaded by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader @ 0xf07b68a0. The memory is accumulated in one instance of java.lang.Thread[], loaded by , which occupies 20,28,67,568 (93.21%) bytes.

Also, my configuration have security protocol SASL_SSL and Sasl dot mechanism is PLAIN

It works most of the time but some time all of a sudden the heap space throws up. I am using confluent Kafka cluster.

I tried increasing the heap space by 200 mb but still it didn't worked out.
I have generated the heap dump and I have given the brief dump in the problem section itself.

Need help if anyone could

Comment: You are creating a lot of threads.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message and the arguments you are passing to the JVM.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez the thread being created are by the Kafka client not our code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.